# Find the safest of the two vehicles

Tags: probability

There is vehicle `A` with 4 engines which can operate safely with at least 3 engines, then there is vehicle `B` which has 2 engines and can operate safely with at least 1 engine. The engine failure probability is `p` and the engine failures are independent. Which of the two vehicles is safer?

I solved in this way:

Vehicle `B` fails when all the engines stop working and the probability is:

$P(0E) = p^{2}  $

Vehicle `A` fails when only 0, 1 or 2 engines are working so:

$P(0E \cup 1E \cup 2E) = P(0E) + P(1E) + P(2E) = p^4 + p^3(1-p) + p^2(1-p)^2$

Is my solving method right?

Comment: Yes, now just compare the two probabilities. The answer will depend on $p$.

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in this solving method. If we call the engines of `Vehicle A`: $a,b,c,d$. The probability of an engine failing is the probability of **any** of them failing while the others don't fail:

$$P(1E) = \\P(Fa)P(1-Fb)P(1-Fc)P(1-Fd) +\\ P(Fb)P(1-Fa)P(1-Fc)P(1-Fd) +\\ P(Fc)P(1-Fa)P(1-Fb)P(1-Fd) +\\ P(Fd)P(1-Fa)P(1-Fb)P(1-Fc)\\ = 4p(1-p)^3$$

Therefore, we have to keep in mind the different permutations to compute the total probability. We have to multiply each of those monomials by $4 \choose i$. The other expression will be correct only for the probability that an *identified engine* fail. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/100697/85067), the same concept is explained.

In this case, there are 4 ways in which only one engine can fail, and there are 6 ways in which two engines can fail. There is only one way in which no engine can fail:
$$P(0E \cup 1E \cup 2E) = p^4 + 4p^3(1-p) + 6p^2(1-p)^2$$

Note that this makes perfect sense if you use the [**binomial theorem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem):
$$P(0E \cup 1E \cup 2E \cup 3E \cup 4E) = \\ p^4 + 4p^3(1-p) + 6p^2(1-p)^2 + 4p(1-p)^3 + (1-p)^4 =\\ \sum_{i=0}^4 {4 \choose i} p^i(1-p)^{4-i} =  (p+(1-p))^2 = 1$$